# Как остановить работу программы, если файл из которого должно было осуществляться чтение оказался пустым?

Tags: c, файлы

Язык C. Как остановить работу программы если файл из которого должно было осуществляться чтение оказался пустым?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
long pos=ftell(file);
if(!(pos>0))
{
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: а не проще проверить результат fread?

Comment: Короче  `if (!ftell(file)) exit(1);` - но почему закрывать программу?